# Maya Python error

Tags: python, maya

new to python. Just started a rigging class that is starting to get into scripting. I found a practice for python and I am having trouble with an error.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
stockPath = "C:\Users\Dryan\Desktop\table.csv"
f = open(stockPath)
data = f.read()
f.close()
print data
```

This is the error I get.

```
> # Error: line 1: IOError: file <maya console> line 4: 22 #
```

Again this is just a practice to get the file of number to print in the script editor. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Since you don't use cmds anywhere in your program, just delete the first line.

Comment: Maya does not print a stack trace of the error, so I recommend you to wrap the operations with the file in a [try/except block](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Anyway, it looks like the error occurs when you try to open the file, make sure it is in the correct location and the name is not misspelled.

Comment: `\t` is a tab character.

Answer (score 3):

The likeliest problem is that you're using backslashes in your file name, so they get interpreted as control characters.  The IO error is because the filename is mangled.

try

```
stockPath = "C:\\Users\\Dryan\\Desktop\\table.csv"  # double slashes to get single slashes in the string
```

or

```
stockPath = "C:/Users/Dryan/Desktop/table.csv"  # it's more python-y to always use right slashes.
```

Comment: or **stockPath = r"C:\Users\Dryan\Desktop\table.csv"**  where the r means raw string that does not escape. In any case its also a maya convention to use / instead of \ like python in general so thats the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

As joojaa said, try to avoid using backslashes when you can. I try to always convert any incoming path to a forward slashes version, and just before outputting it I normalize it using os.path.normpath.

```
clean_path = any_path_i_have_to_deal_with.replace("\\", "/") 
# do stuff with it 
# (concat, XML save, assign to a node attribute...)
print os.path.normpath(clean_path) # back to the OS version
```

Comment: That's not going to help here.

Comment: Yes, because the \t is a tab in the literal OP created. But otherwise yes.